# What' the meaning of method-generic-function?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, clos

I'm learning common-lisp and CLOS.

I started with the tutorial from http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/clos-tutorial/

In Section 4.3, it mentioned that

> A generic function is a lisp function which is associated with a set of methods and dispatches them when it's invoked.

It also present two functions `generic-function-methods` and `method-generic-function`:

```
CL-USER 63 > #'my-describe
#<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION MY-DESCRIBE 21111C2A>

CL-USER 64 > (generic-function-methods #'my-describe)
(#<STANDARD-METHOD MY-DESCRIBE NIL (T) 2110B544>
 #<STANDARD-METHOD MY-DESCRIBE NIL (ANIMAL) 21111BF4>)

CL-USER 65 > (method-generic-function (car *))
#<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION MY-DESCRIBE 21111C2A>
```

I can understand the 1st one (i.e. `generic-function-methods`), it tells me the set of methods in the generic function `my-describe`.

But what about the 2nd one (i.e. `(method-generic-function (car *))`)?

I don't quite understand it.

PS: I tried to use this function in REPL, but failed:

```
CL-USER> #'method-generic-function

undefined.
   [Condition of type UNDEFINED-FUNCTION]
```

My environment is SBCL + quicklisp + slime.

Can I use this function in SBCL?

Thanks.

---

Update:

I seem to understand the meaning of `method-generic-function`:

It just return the generic-function from the particular method `#<STANDARD-METHOD MY-DESCRIBE NIL (T) 2110B544>`.

The confusing thing is the `*` in `(car *)`, it seems return the value of the last expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `Method-generic-function` gives you the generic function that the given method is associated with.
- `Method-generic-function` is not imported into the `cl-user` package in SBCL.  You will find it in `sb-mop` (so, `sb-mop:method-generic-function`).  The MOP is not entirely incorporated in the Common Lisp standard.
- For portable use of the entire MOP, use the library “Closer to MOP” (`closer-mop`).
- In the REPL, `*` refers to the first return value of the last evaluated expression.  In your case, that was the list of methods returned by `generic-function-methods`.  So you see that these two are more or less inverse functions in this one-to-many relation.